# Trigger value, call for table column and concenate with text

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am not able to solve that [CREATE TRIGGER VALUE] needs to call for table content and concatenate with text. For details of expected result, see below result area.

Currently the code can be run In one execution, creating 2 lines in account_log as expected.

I have marked the line that I suspect needs to be update with [<-- Needs update?].

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS test6;
USE test6;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS account;
CREATE TABLE account
(
    `id` CHAR(4) PRIMARY KEY,
    `name` VARCHAR(25),
    `price` DECIMAL(4, 2)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS account_log;
CREATE TABLE account_log
(
    `log_id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `timestamp` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `description` VARCHAR(60)
);


DELETE FROM account;
INSERT INTO account
VALUES
    ('1', 'Adam', 10),
    ('2', 'Eva', 7)
;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS product_update;

DELIMITER ;;

    CREATE PROCEDURE product_update()

    BEGIN
    UPDATE account
        SET
            name = "Ad"
        WHERE
            id = "1";
    END
    ;;

DELIMITER ;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS after_account_update;

CREATE TRIGGER after_account_update
    AFTER UPDATE
    ON account
    FOR EACH ROW
    INSERT INTO
        account_log (`description`)
    VALUES
        ('Update detected: Productid: [product-1]') -- <-- Needs update?
;

-- ----------------------------
-- Provoke triggers to execute.
-- ----------------------------
CALL product_update();
CALL product_update();

SELECT * FROM account_log;
```

**Results:**

The result looks currently like this:

(the content of description is plain text).

```
+--------+---------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| log_id | timestamp           | description                             |
+--------+---------------------+-----------------------------------------+
|      1 | 2019-03-28 18:14:58 | Update detected: Productid: [product-1] |
|      2 | 2019-03-28 18:14:58 | Update detected: Productid: [product-1] |
+--------+---------------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

I need the result to look like this

(where the values 1 and 2 in table description, comes from table account, column [id]):

```
+--------+---------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| log_id | timestamp           | description                             |
+--------+---------------------+-----------------------------------------+
|      1 | 2019-03-28 18:14:58 | Update detected: Productid: 1           |
|      2 | 2019-03-28 18:14:58 | Update detected: Productid: 2           |
+--------+---------------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works by using below TRIGGER VALUES CONCAT:

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_account_insert
    AFTER INSERT
    ON account
    FOR EACH ROW
    INSERT INTO
        account_log (`description`)
    VALUES
    (
    CONCAT("Update detected: Productid: ", "[", NEW.id, "]", ".")
    )
;
```